# Make cells look like buttons

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make Excel cells look like buttons without actually inserting buttons.

```
For Each myCell In Range(BoardSize)
    With myCell
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders.Weight = xlThick
        .Borders.Color = RGB(110, 110, 110)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(180, 180, 180)
    End With

        myCell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        myCell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Next myCell
```

It works for one cell:

[image]

but in a large range it looks like this:

[image]

What I want is something, without using actual command buttons, like:

[image]

Comment: It will never work the way you have planned. Look at your ONE CELL example. There is only one border between cells, but your idea assumes that there are two borders between adjacent cells. Since there is only one shared border, the code has to decide what to apply to the common borders, and it defaults to using the TOP and LEFT border settings.

Comment: You could make something like this work if you were open to hiding one column between visibly adjacent cells (and one row as well for the vertical).

Comment: you are setting all the edges to white. Check your code: when you set to white the `top edge` of a cell, at the same time you are setting the `bottom edge` of the cell above it. same goes for left edge and right edge. edges are **common** between adjacent cells.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I am making a minesweeper. Since,I have known VBA only for a month, adding an extra lines in between would be too much more work for me. lol Thanks Excel Hero!

Comment: I agree ASH, but there seems like no other way to give it 3D like feel to a cell if I don't give it a shave and light. I couldn't figure out how to have an adjacent border to have two colors... lol Being new to VBA, that was the best I could think of:) Thanks ASH

Comment: And doing this with buttons is out of the question?

Comment: lol,my answer would has to be depend. I would use buttons if that wouldn't complicate the coding too much for making the minesweeper.

Answer (score 2):

```
For Each mycell In Range(BoardSize)
isblack = mycell.Row Mod 2 = 0 Xor mycell.Column Mod 2 = 0
    With mycell
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders.Weight = xlThick
        .Borders.Color = RGB(110, 110, 110)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(180, 180, 180)
    End With
If Not isblack Then
        mycell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        mycell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If
Next mycell
```

Another version with a minor artifact. It skipps odd rows and odd columns

```
 Dim mycell As Range
For Each mycell In  Range(BoardSize)
evenrow = mycell.Row Mod 2 = 0
evencol = mycell.Column Mod 2 = 0
isblack = evenrow Xor evencol
    With mycell
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders.Weight = xlThick
        .Borders.Color = RGB(110, 110, 110)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(180, 180, 180)
    End With
If Not isblack Then
        mycell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        mycell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If
If evenrow Or evencol Then mycell.Borders.Color = RGB(180, 180, 180)
If evencol And mycell.ColumnWidth <> 0.1 Then mycell.ColumnWidth = 0.1 Else mycell.ColumnWidth = 5
If evenrow And mycell.RowHeight <> 1 Then mycell.RowHeight = 1 Else mycell.RowHeight = 30
Next mycell
```

Comment: That is a nice effect and I'll upvote it as such, though unfortunately it isn't quite what OP is looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to come up with this code. It isn't exactly what I was going for but the result looks very pretty. Thank you:)